# Failed app updates with multiple authorities in content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, authority

When I have more than one authority listed for a content provider for my Android app, the app will install fine, but will fail when I try to **replace/update** the app via `adb install -r`, I get a failed installation:

> Failed to install app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.test.testApp-1: Can't install because provider name test2 (in package com.test.testApp) is already used by com.test.testApp]

My app updates work fine while I have a single authority listed, but as the Android documentation states, [multiple authorities are supported](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#auth).

> Multiple authorities are listed by separating their names with a semicolon.

Here's a snippet of my manifest file with the authorities:

```java
<provider
    android:name=".data.ContentProvider"
    android:authorities="test1;test2"
    ... />
```

It seems like the first authority is being treated differently from the second two authorities. When I try to reinstall the app, I get the failure message of `provider name test2 (in package com.test.testApp) is already used by com.test.testApp`, even if I change the above authorities to `"test2;test3"`.

**Has anyone had success with app updates using multiple authorities for a single content provider?**